# Как сделать клик по условию?

Tags: jquery, css3

К примеру, имеются некие фото, при клике на одну группу должно появится надпись `"fallowing"` или `"понравилось"` при втором клике  `"разонравилось"` или вообще без разницы что...
Уже пробовал :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var someDiv = $('.item > .fallower');
  var parent = $('body');

  someDiv.on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('visible');
    $(parent).append("<div class='overboard'><h1>falloving</h1></div>")
  });


  $(body).dblclick(function() {
    $(this).append("<h2 class='note'>your not fallower</h2>")
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  width: 60%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-ites: center;
}

.item {
  width: 45%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  margin: 4px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {}

.item:nth-child(2) {}

.item:nth-child(3) {}

.item:nth-child(4) {}

.elem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35%;
}

.item:nth-child(1) .elem:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

.item:nth-child(1) .elem:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}

.item:nth-child(1) .elem:nth-child(3) {
  background: pink;
}

.item:nth-child(2) .elem:nth-child(1) {
  background: #ccc;
}

.item:nth-child(2) .elem:nth-child(2) {
  background: yellow;
}

.item:nth-child(2) .elem:nth-child(3) {
  background: coral;
}

.item:nth-child(3) .elem:nth-child(1) {
  background: blue;
}

.item:nth-child(3) .elem:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.item:nth-child(3) .elem:nth-child(3) {
  background: darkred;
}

.item:nth-child(4) .elem:nth-child(1) {
  background: lime;
}

.item:nth-child(4) .elem:nth-child(2) {
  background: indigo;
}

.item:nth-child(4) .elem:nth-child(3) {
  background: violet;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
}

.item .fallower {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 0;
}

.item .fallower {
  background: #cc0011;
  padding: 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.fallower.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.ask {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  right: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.overboard {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.overboard h1 {
  color: red;
}

.note {
  color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <div class="item">

    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <span class="ask">faloving?</span>
    <p class="fallower"><i>faloved</i> &#10003; </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">

    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <span class="ask">faloving?</span>
    <p class="fallower"><i>faloved</i> &#10003; </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">

    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <span class="ask">faloving?</span>
    <p class="fallower"><i>faloved</i> &#10003; </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">

    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <span class="ask">faloving?</span>
    <p class="fallower"><i>faloved</i> &#10003; </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

В общем не получается обработать второй клик ... 
Каким образом это делается ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для таких вещей обычно используют так называемый флажок.
Создается некая переменная, присваиваем  ей (обычно используют `true & false`) и при каждом клике меняем значение на `true или false`.

И если я правильно понял, то `.dblclick` - это двойной клик, а не последующий.

```js
var flag = true;
$('.items').click(function() {
  if (flag == true) {
    $(this).text('Нравится');
    flag = false;
  } else {
    $(this).text('Разонравилось');
    flag = true;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  width: 60%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items"></div>
```

Comment: Я даже не видел твой ответ. Копия твоего ответа получилась... Как будто у тя скопировал))))))

Comment: смотри какая штука получается : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/RMzypd он клик на другом item считает за клик на этом ... если убрать absolute это будет видно хотя и так заметно .. кликни на первом и потом на третьем ...будет fack

Comment: Ну так правильно работает. Если исходить их твоего кода

Comment: Я понял что ты хочешь

Comment: как в чат перейти ?

Comment: Тебе надо что бы событие обрабатывалось на каждый блок по отдельности

Comment: Ща скину ссылку

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76048/discussion-between---and-air).

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, ну как разобрался? Получилось на `JQ` перевести?

Comment: у меня супрга уехала в больничку ... буду делать как она приедет .. щас с сыном сижу ... он дэцел ещё

Comment: Ок. Будь другом скинь потом ссылку я гляну, может чего из `JQ` для ся подчеркну

Comment: не получилось перегнать в jq

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, оформи новый вопрос

Comment: да нее.... пофигу... сам разберус со временем ... я не профи ... для себя делаю ... и потому не тороплюсь

Answer (score 1):

Обработал второй клик подряд таким образом :

пример развернуть на всю страницу

```js
var flag = 0;

$('.fallower').click(function() {
  if (flag == 0) {
    $('body').append('<br>', "nice")
    flag = 1;
  } else {
    $('body').append('<br>', "oh my good")
    flag = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  width: 60%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-ites: center;
}

.item {
  width: 45%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  margin: 4px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {}

.item:nth-child(2) {}

.item:nth-child(3) {}

.item:nth-child(4) {}

.elem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35%;
}

.item:nth-child(1) .elem:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

.item:nth-child(1) .elem:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}

.item:nth-child(1) .elem:nth-child(3) {
  background: pink;
}

.item:nth-child(2) .elem:nth-child(1) {
  background: #ccc;
}

.item:nth-child(2) .elem:nth-child(2) {
  background: yellow;
}

.item:nth-child(2) .elem:nth-child(3) {
  background: coral;
}

.item:nth-child(3) .elem:nth-child(1) {
  background: blue;
}

.item:nth-child(3) .elem:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightblue;
}

.item:nth-child(3) .elem:nth-child(3) {
  background: darkred;
}

.item:nth-child(4) .elem:nth-child(1) {
  background: lime;
}

.item:nth-child(4) .elem:nth-child(2) {
  background: indigo;
}

.item:nth-child(4) .elem:nth-child(3) {
  background: violet;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
}

.item .fallower {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 0;
}

.item .fallower {
  background: #cc0011;
  padding: 2px;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.fallower.visible {
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.ask {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  right: 0;
  background: #ccc;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.overboard {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.overboard h1 {
  color: red;
}

.note {
  color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: lightblue;
}

.fallower.visible:after {
  content: "fallowering";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.i {
  color: red;
}

.r {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="items">
  <div class="item">

    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <span class="ask">faloving?</span>
    <p class="fallower"><i>faloved</i> &#10003; </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">

    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <span class="ask">faloving?</span>
    <p class="fallower"><i>faloved</i> &#10003; </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">

    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <span class="ask">faloving?</span>
    <p class="fallower"><i>faloved</i> &#10003; </p>
  </div>
  <div class="item">

    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <span class="ask">faloving?</span>
    <p class="fallower"><i>faloved</i> &#10003; </p>
  </div>
</div>
```