# Редактирования комментария jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

В общем мой код:

```js
$(".edit-event").on("click", function(event) {
  var current_text = $(this).parents(".comment").find(".showComment").click();

  var edit = $('<textarea>', {
    id: 'editComment',
    width: "620px",
    class: "form-control",
    height: "120px",
    placeholder: "Напишите Ваш отзыв"
  }).text(current_text.text());
  current_text.replaceWith(edit.appendTo(".media-list"));
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootstraptema.ru/plugins/2016/bootsnav/bootsnav.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bootstraptema.ru/plugins/2016/bootsnav/bootsnav.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <ul class="media-list">
    <div class="comment">
      <a class="pull-left">
        <img src="http://ru/temp/public/img/default_avatar.png" alt="" class="img-circle" width="68" height="48">
      </a>
      <div class="media-body">
        <p id="admin">GreatAdmin</p>
        <span class="text-muted"><h4 class="date">2018-04-17 15:18:04</h4></span>
        <p class="showComment">
          <a>The battle begins, and sixteen teams across the globe are fighting towards one goal – to win the League of Legends World Championship. To kick off the start of the action, we set out to craft a war cry to rally behind. Whether you’re a solo queue warrior or fightin</a>
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-warning pull-right edit-event">
          <i class="material-icons" title="Редактировать">edit</i>
        </button>
      </div>
  </ul>
```

Подскажите, как мне сделать, чтобы когда кликало на "edit" второй раз, комментарий возвращался в прежнее состояние (на данный момент там добавляется еще одна форма, что в корне неправильно)
И если можете, то подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать к примеру код более грамотным. Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Просто проверяйте есть ли уже форма и если есть убирать, если нет, добавлять.

Comment: Используй обычный флажок

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать клик по условию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814400/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {
  if ($("div").attr("contenteditable") == 'false') {
    $("div").attr("contenteditable", "true");
    $("div").css({ border: "1px solid black" });
  } else {
    $("div").attr("contenteditable", "false");
    $("div").css({ border: "none" });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script><div contenteditable="false">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Eum libero earum tenetur recusandae soluta non quasi, totam nobis illum alias ad aspernatur! Consectetur repellendus incidunt qui ut obcaecati non iste.
</div>
<button>edit</button>
```

А если вам нужно сразу отправлять данные на сервер то ajaxom по нажатии при завершении редактирования.
Если брать ваш случай то при 1 нажатии можно кнопки давать любой атрибут в false и при втором нажатии проверять его.

Comment: Сделал лучшим ответом, но как-то сильно просто сделано

Comment: Вас пугает простота?) Можно доработать до более сложного с focus и т.д:) Но я дал вам зачато более простой для вашей идеи) У меня где-то cms своя с visual edit написаная на contenteditable есть:)

Comment: Не подскажеешь, ставлю к себе, у меня в итоге не работает мышка. То есть нажимаю на любое место, и у меня в самое начало перебирается. Запустил этот код в обычном файле все работает, а у меня не работает. Вроде сделал все по такой же системе

Comment: Хм, не знаю с чем связано это(